# Real money poker on Android?

Tags: poker-tools

Are there any apps available on Android on which you can play real money Poker? :D

I only found this one:
http://www.888poker.com/poker-promotions/android.htm

Has anyone used it?

Comment: I voted to close this since it's not about poker.

Comment: @Radu - disagree with you. Its not exactly about the game, but it is related to it exactly as "where can I find books" questions is.

Answer (score 5):

You can play real money poker on both [Pokerstars](http://www.pokerstars.com/mobile/) and [PKR](http://m.pkr.com/en/) on android devices.

I havent used either on android, but they are both pretty good on iOS.

Comment: on android devices, you cannot play on real money. Only pokerstars for iOS enable playing with real money

Comment: @amigal You can play Pokerstars for real money on Android. You just have to download it from the PokerStars website and not the play store. (In the play store there is a pokerstars.net app which is play money only. The real money one is pokerstars.com).

Comment: Are there any online websites that do not require downloads?

Answer (score 1):

sealswithclubs.eu has a native poker application (available for download on its site) but it requires bitcoins to play.  Bitcoins make depositing and withdrawing easy and it is much less frustrating than traditional online poker rooms.

Answer (score 1):

[Carbon Poker](http://www.carbonpoker.ag) is another good poker site with a mobile site works well with either Iphone or Andriod products. They also still accept US players which is key for me.

Comment: I appreciate your point of view, but if you will link to poker sites, do so without your affiliate link as that isn't acceptable here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best real money poker APP for Android right now is [Pokerstars](http://www.pokerstars.com/mobile/). This software is really well done. The second, in my oppinion is [Full Tilt Rush Poker app for Android](http://www.fulltiltpoker.com/poker/mobile). Those are the places with more people playing so you find more diversity.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Bwin Poker on my girlfriends iphone, there is an android app as well which i installed on my galaxy S4 , but an error occurs and it says that my specific device is not allowed. so i guess some other android phones are supported.

let me know if u managed to install bwin real poker or something was the name.
thanks

As well Partypoker seems to have something :

http://www.pokernews.com/news/2012/12/partypoker-launch-real-money-android-app-14038.htm

yes they both work and really shit though u can download pokerstars for android and iphone off the pokerstars website

Answer (score 0):

switchpoker.com is good if you want to play more than one table at a time. It allows you to multi-table on up to tables on screen at once.

Answer (score 0):

I know Full Tilt had real money Rush Poker on android a couple of years ago. Not sure what's happened since Black Friday though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know actually. In Google Play there aren't any real money poker app. Try  Enterra Poker Pro app.